# Does Lumbar roll for back support do anything?

Tags: back, posture

Does keeping a lumbar roll behind ones back when sitting on a chair good for your back?

Comment: For me, it prolonged the problem I had. I can't say anything about how it would work for other people or other issues but for me it was not the answer.

Comment: Do some deadlifts, squats and rows. That's much much much more effective. If you make yourself even weaker by removing all the work your muscles have to do, you may regret this later in life. This is the philosophy that was popular until the 80ies or even later in some countries. Rest and make everything easy. What we got from that is army of older people that live in constant pain. When you're fit, you will be able to do things even in your 90ies. If you're really sick or injured that is. If you have a very good reason, listen to a medical professional and not the internet

Comment: @Raditz yes that's true,thank you,  but I was looking for ,does lumbar roll do anything at all?

Comment: Why do you care? Does it do anything? Of course it does. But that's like asking "how do I get from Norway to south Africa - would being dragged by a snail work?"